# Запрос работает в postman, но не в python requests

Tags: python, postman, cloudflare

Пытаюсь отправить get-запрос в postman -- всё работает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как только пытаюсь сделать то же самое в requests, вылетает cloudflare

```
import requests
import json

headers = {
    "accept-language": "ru",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 "
                  "Safari/537.36 "
}

response = requests.get('https://www.visa.com.ua/cmsapi/fx/rates?amount=1&fee=2&utcConvertedDate=12%2F11%2F2022&exchangedate=12%2F11%2F2022&fromCurr=UAH&toCurr=USD', headers=headers).text
print(response)
```

Cloudflare:

```
<noscript>
            <div id="challenge-error-title">
                <div class="h2">
                    <span class="icon-wrapper">
                        <div class="heading-icon warning-icon"></div>
                    </span>
                    <span id="challenge-error-text">
                        Enable JavaScript and cookies to continue
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </noscript>
```

Буду очень признателен, если поможете

Comment: Заголовки(headers) и куки(cookie) из постмана кто добавлять будет?

Comment: cloudflare обходите